# Python Wordle Game Problem: Python 3 Hidden Errors

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, testing, error-handling

So I have an assignment to do where we have to make a wordle game in python, my code has passed most of the tests but it hasn't passed some hidden tests, as they are hidden I'm am finding it hard to see where I went wrong, can someone help me please. Here is my code.

```py
def get_player_guess():
    guess = input("Please enter your guess: ").lower()
    if len(guess) == 5 and guess.isalpha():
        return guess
    else:
        while True:
            guess = input("Your guess must have 5 letters: ").lower()
            if len(guess) == 5 and guess.isalpha():
                return guess


def update_game_state(word, guess, game_state):
    new_game_state = ""

    # Count the frequency of letters in the word
    word_frequency = {}
    for letter in word:
        word_frequency[letter] = word_frequency.get(letter, 0) + 1

    # Count the frequency of letters in the guess
    guess_frequency = {}
    for letter in guess:
        guess_frequency[letter] = guess_frequency.get(letter, 0) + 1

    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess[i] == word[i]:
            new_game_state += guess[i].upper() + ' '
            word_frequency[guess[i]] -= 1
            guess_frequency[guess[i]] -= 1
        elif guess[i] in word and word_frequency[guess[i]] > 0 and guess_frequency[guess[i]] <= word_frequency[guess[i]]:
            new_game_state += guess[i].lower() + ' '
            word_frequency[guess[i]] -= 1
            guess_frequency[guess[i]] -= 1
        else:
            new_game_state += "_ "

    return new_game_state


def play_round(word):
    game_state = "_" * len(word)
    newword=''
    for i in word:
        newword+=i.upper() +' '

    guesses = 0
    solved = False

    while guesses < 6 and not solved:
        guesses += 1
        print(f"Guess {guesses}:\n")

        guess = get_player_guess()

        game_state = update_game_state(word, guess, game_state)
        print(game_state)
        
        print()

        if game_state == newword:
            solved = True

    return guesses, solved


round_results = play_round("shell")
print(f"Number of guesses: {round_results[0]}, Is solved? {round_results[1]}")
```

[hidden test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meZCk.png)

Comment: Since we also don't know what the hidden tests are, it would be very difficult to guess what might be wrong and impossible to verify such guesses. Therefore this question is not really reproducible, it's probably better to ask your teacher.